# Read Disconected Graph in igraph for python

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I'd like to know the best way to read a disconected undirected graph using igraph for python. For instance, if I have the simple graph in which 0 is linked to 1 and 2 is a node not connected to any other. I couldn't get igraph to read it from a edgelist format(Graph.Read_Edgelist(...)), because every line must be an edge, so the following is not allowed:

```
0 1
2
```

I've been just wondering if adjacency matrix is my only/best option in this case (I could get it to work through this representation)? I'd rather a format in which I could understand the data by looking it (something really hard when it comes to matrix format).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the LGL format which allows isolated vertices (see `Graph.Read_LGL`). The format looks like this:

```
# nodeID
nodeID2
nodeID3
# nodeID2
nodeID4
nodeID5
nodeID
# isolatedNode
# nodeID5
```

I think you get the basic idea; lines starting with a hash mark indicate that a new node is being defined. After this, the lines specify the neighbors of the node that has just been defined. If you need an isolated node, you just specify the node ID prepended by a hash mark in the line, then continue with the next node.

More information about the LGL format is to be found [here](http://lgl.sourceforge.net/#FileFormat).

Another fairly readable format that you might want to examine is the [GML format](http://www.fim.uni-passau.de/fileadmin/files/lehrstuhl/brandenburg/projekte/gml/gml-technical-report.pdf) which igraph also supports.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now I have the following problem: I'm doing some calculations in two different graphs, but after read the graph, igraph relabels the nodes' ids, so I can't access the edges directly by their original ids. Because of that, I can't be sure if getting, for instance, the edge (1,4) in one graph, it will be the same edge in the other one. Is it possible to force igraph not to relabel nodes' ids?

Comment: The original IDs are kept in the "name" vertex attribute if you use the LGL or NCOL formats. Alternatively, if all your IDs are numeric and you do not have weights, use a simple edge list format.